# solr search query issue in 8.4.1

Tags: solr

I'm facing the issue in solr search query.

we have document for the products list and there is a product named "W240 Cashew Nuts 00" in the document.
When we try to search product exactly "W240 Cashew Nuts 00" then it doesn't come in the search result but when we search with "Cashew Nuts 00" it comes in the result.

Example given below

When we search with "Cashew nut 00" it comes in the result

```
"params":{
  "q":"product_related_kword:\"Cashew nut 00\"",
  "fl":"product_related_kword,product_slno",
  "fq":"product_slno:14598137",
  "rows":"1000",
  "debugQuery":"on",
  "_":"1631868976348"}},
"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
  {
    "product_slno":"14598137",
    "product_related_kword":["W240 Cashew Nuts 00"]}]
},
```

but when we search with "W240 Cashew nut 00" it does not show in the result

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "q":"product_related_kword:\"W240 Cashew nut 00\"",
      "fl":"product_related_kword,product_slno",
      "fq":"product_slno:14598137",
      "rows":"1000",
      "debugQuery":"on",
      "_":"1631868976348"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }
```

What could be the reason for the above issue?

Please help

Comment: What is the field type of `product_related_kword`?

Comment: try to use string type which does not tokenize the text and would help for exact match. Else use keywordtokenizer with lowercasefilter combination as fieldtype and use for your field

Comment: field type is "text_general"
<field name="product_related_kword" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" />

Comment: The text "W240 Cashew Nuts 00" in a text general works by default, you can validate this in the "Analysis" screen in the Admin UI. I wonder if the extra `fq` (set to `product_slno:14598137` in your example) is having an effect on this.